# Why hidden field values not get passed to controller Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I have a form in `ioinc v1.`

```
<form name="add-form">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.usersId" ng-value="{{userId}}"/>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="{{LoggedInUserId}}"/>

        <div class="col col-center">
        <div class="list list-inset1">              
            <label class="item item-input input-field">Send Message:

                <textarea name="comment" id="comment-textarea" cols="6" rows="6" ng-model="data.message">
                </textarea>
                </label> 

            <button ui-sref="app.profile" style="background-color:red;" class="button button-full button-assertive ink" ng-click="sendMessage()">Send</button>

        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

But on click I am not able to get the values of above hidden field in controller its says

> undefined

.

```
//Controller is.

 $scope.sendMessage = function() {      
  $scope.data.userId = $scope.data.userId;
  $scope.data.loggedInUserId = $scope.data.loggedInUserId;

  $ionicLoading.show();    
   messagingService.storeMessages($scope.data.message,$scope.data.userId,$scope.data.loggedInUserId)

});
```

Can anyone assist me what is wrong with this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try use `<input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.usersId" ng-init="data.usersId = userId" />`

Comment: I need to pass value also.value parameter why did you remove?

Comment: <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.usersId" ng-value="12"/>
I have like this in my view

Comment: so add `ng-init="data.usersId = userId"` to it.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.usersId" ng-value="{{userId}}" ng-init="data.usersId = userId"/>
            <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="{{LoggedInUserId}}" ng-init="data.loggedInUserId = loggedInUserId"/>
    
Still undefined. I got

Answer (score 0):

Is $scope.data initialized in the controller prior to the form function?
This might be caused if it's not.

Try the following code us

```
 $scope.data = {
   'userId'= null,
   'loggedInUserId': "",
   'message'=''

 }
 $scope.sendMessage = function() {      
    $ionicLoading.show();     
    messagingService.storeMessages( 
    $scope.data.message,
    $scope.data.userId,
    $scope.data.loggedInUserId)
   });
```

Comment: $scope.data = {
        'userId': "",
       'loggedInUserId': "",
       'message':''
    };

Tried but its syas null and undefined on click

Comment: Have you tried this code with an init directive as per Hadi's 2ne comment?

Comment: <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.usersId"  ng-init="data.usersId = {{userId}}"/>
<input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId"  ng-init="data.loggedInUserId = {{LoggedInUserId}}"/>

$scope.data = {
        'userId': "",
       'loggedInUserId': "",
       'message':''
    };
$scope.sendMessage = function() {      
    $ionicLoading.show();     
    messagingService.storeMessages( 
    $scope.data.message,
    $scope.data.userId,
    $scope.data.loggedInUserId)
   });
But still not getting values.

Comment: remove `{{..}}` from it and `ng-value`

Comment: <textarea name="comment" id="comment-textarea" cols="6" rows="6" ng-model="data.message">
                    </textarea>
I am only getting this values. not hidden field values

Comment: <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.usersId" ng-value="userId" ng-init="data.usersId = userId" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-hide" style="">
<input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="LoggedInUserId" ng-init="data.loggedInUserId = LoggedInUserId}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-hide" value="593f94e9d22647f019372969" style="">  
              
            can you plz check is anythig missing in this form.Still am not getting values.

Comment: Now I got only one values LoggedInUserId but not userId.

Answer (score 0):

The values on ng-model are different to the ones in ng-value.
data is not initialized.

Look at this snippet it may help.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MessageController', ['$scope', MessageController]);

function MessageController($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.data = {};

    //Data initialized on ctrl start:
    $scope.data.userId = "1234";
    $scope.data.loggedInUserId = "test";

  }


  $scope.sendMessage = function() {
    $scope.data.userId = $scope.data.userId;
    $scope.data.loggedInUserId = $scope.data.loggedInUserId;

    console.log('Do something with data', $scope.data.userId, $scope.data.loggedInUserId,
      $scope.data.message);
  }

  $scope.init();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MessageController">
    <form name="add-form">
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.usersId" ng-value="{{data.userId}}" />
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="{{data.loggedInUserId}}" />

      <div class="col col-center">
        <div class="list list-inset1">
          <label class="item item-input input-field">Send Message:

                <textarea name="comment" id="comment-textarea" cols="6" rows="6" ng-model="data.message">
                </textarea>
                </label>

          <button style="background-color:red;" class="button button-full button-assertive ink" ng-click="sendMessage()">Send</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need dynamic values from views not defined as static before

Comment: I don´t know if I understand what you mean, but I am sure your trouble comes because of $scope.data not being initialized and/or ng-value not defined correctly (notice the {{data.userId}} instead of {{userId}})

Comment: <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.userId" ng-value="userId" ng-init="data.userId = userId" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-hide" style="" value="345345">

<input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="LoggedInUserId" ng-init="data.loggedInUserId = LoggedInUserId" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-hide" value="593f94e9d22647f019372969" style="">

Comment: app.controller('CommunicationController', function ($scope,$rootScope,$state,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,messagingService,sessionService) {
    
    $rootScope.showMessage = false;  
    $scope.data = {
        'userId': "",
        'loggedInUserId': "",
        'message':''
    };

 $scope.sendMessage = function() {     
      
        $ionicLoading.show(); 
        
        alert($scope.data.message); alert($scope.data.userId);alert($scope.data.loggedInUserId);
        }
}):

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="add-form">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.userId" ng-value="{{userId}}"/>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="{{LoggedInUserId}}"/>

        <div class="col col-center">
        <div class="list list-inset1">              
            <label class="item item-input input-field">Send Message:

                <textarea name="comment" id="comment-textarea" cols="6" rows="6" ng-model="data.message">
                </textarea>
                </label> 

            <button ui-sref="app.profile" style="background-color:red;" class="button button-full button-assertive ink" ng-click="sendMessage(data)">Send</button>

        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

and for fetching data use this:

```
       <script>
                    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                        $scope.sendMessage = function(data) {     

                      $scope.userId = $scope.data.userId;
                      $scope.loggedInUserId = $scope.data.loggedInUserId;
                      $scope.message = $scope.data.message;

        $ionicLoading.show();    
 messagingService.storeMessages($scope.message,$scope.userId,$scope.loggedInUserId)
                }
       }]);
            </script>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined, its throw this erro

Comment: obviously the data which you passed in hidden is not contents any value...because its hidden value if you want to use values of that input filed then use <input type="text">

Comment: its contain values already, check it please.

<input type="hidden" ng-model="data.userId" ng-value="45454" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" style="">

Comment: $scope.sendMessage = function(data) {
}

its showing data unused

Comment: app.controller('CommunicationController', function ($scope,$rootScope,$state,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,messagingService,sessionService) {
      $scope.data = {};
 $scope.sendMessage = function(data) {
      
      $scope.userId = $scope.data.userId;
      $scope.loggedInUserId = $scope.data.loggedInUserId;
      $scope.message = $scope.data.message;        
     alert($scope.message); ($scope.loggedInUserId);alert($scope.userId);
        }
});
Please have a look.

Comment: have you fetch any value for this?

Comment: Yes, hidden fields values I am fetching them from controller before submiting form ng-click.

Comment: Both field has values,but these are not posted on ng-click.

 <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.userId" ng-value="345345" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-hide" style="">
        
        <input type="text" ng-show="false" ng-model="data.loggedInUserId" ng-value="593f94e9d22647f019372969" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-hide" style="">

Comment: but now u r using <input type="text"> and that is the reason you get values in controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147039/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-hitarthi-panchal).